# Push notification not received

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

We are connecting to 'gateway.push.apple.com 2195' from a c# console with a right device token and production certificate. Ssl authentication went fine and no issues reported but the device doesn't recieve any alert message or badge. Device is registered to recieve notifications. [Settings->Notifications is set to ON for badge, alert and sound]. We are using apns-sharp-1.0.3.0 c# source code. what else could go wrong and how to debug the issue. 
P.S Note: One thing we noticed, the call back routine (OnAsyncRead.IsCompleted) hasn't been completed and we have to Dispose() it forcibly. Desperately looking out for a solution, anyone's feedback would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

small time fix only - sleep the thread before closing and disposing - giving time for the APN to be sent.